# Applying scale to a rigified object

Tags: rigging, armature, transforms, rigify

A model with a rigify rig that I'm working with is too big in size and I would like to scale it down and apply the scale. However, the model gets messed up after directly applying the scale and ends up in a weird position. (This issue doesn't occur with location or scale.)

I've tried applying scale to the metarig and regenerating the rig, as well as un-parenting the mesh and re-parenting by scaling separately. Neither of these methods have worked. Is there any way to apply scale to the rig effectively?

Comment: You could try parenting both the armature and the mesh to an empty and scaling the empty.